# What's the secret text?

Tags: cipher, number-sequence

Poem:

The sequence leads you there

The "shift" is not that rare

It is ancient, you will see

Jupiter is the key

14 15 92 65 35 89 79 ??

OGSULLOIOGRREYSGXZ

Hint

> Complete the number sequence and find out how it will help you encode the letters

Big Hint

> The number sequence is well known, the cipher was established by a Roman guy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secret text is

> iamofficiallysmart

The sequence is

> The decimal digits of pi, so the next two digits are 32

Then using

> A Caesar cipher with shift 32 gives the answer I AM OFFICIALLY SMART!

Comment: Very well done :-)

Comment: Where does Jupiter come in?

Comment: Jupiter is the most important god in the Roman religion, thus narrowing the used cipher down to one used by the Romans.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer:

> iamofficiallysmart

So for the first part I figured out the missing number was:

> 32

This is because the sequence of numbers is just:

> Pi (excluding the 3 of course)

Then to translate the text:

> We know there are 26 letters of the alphabet so we take 32-26 = 6 and we shift each letter by -6 to get back to the original plain text.

Comment: Ah a couple minutes too late with the answer!

Comment: Yep, good job :)

Answer (score 2):

After Decode OGSULLOIOGRREYSGXZ this Answer:

> IAMOFFICIALLYSMART

14 15 92 65 35 89 79 ??

> Next number is 32 (it comes after 15 decimal of PI - 3.14159265358979**32**3846)

Final result:

> It will get after correct shift +6 (alphabets 26+6= 32) via [Caesar Cipher](https://www.dcode.fr/caesar-cipher)  i.e **+6 IAMOFFICIALLYSMART**